# SwiftUI - How to pass Date() as a string to another view?

Tags: swift, xcode, date, swiftui

First I have following code:

```
@State private var date = Date()

var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .long
    return formatter
}
```

Then in a Form inside a NavigationView there is a date picker like that:

```
DatePicker(selection: $date, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) {
    Text("Datum")
}
```

Now I would like to send the date value as a string to another view like that:

```
Button("Add") {
    let item = ExpenseItem(validDate: self.date)
    self.expenses.items.append(item)
}
```

But then I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'String'

So how do I assign the first part with dateFormatter to the date to make it a string? I don't understand that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821737/swiftui-question-passing-a-variable-to-another-view

Comment: You can try `let item = ExpenseItem(validDate: dateFormatter.string(from: date!))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account your snapshot code it should be

```
Button("Add") {
    let item = ExpenseItem(validDate: self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date))
    self.expenses.items.append(item)
}
```